# Google form - не могу найти frame

Tags: python, selenium, google-forms

Пытаюсь через selenium (python) передать данные из csv в форму гугл. Одна строка - одна форма. После окончания ввода запроса необходимо кликнуть "Отправить форму заново", но после этого страница не обновляется для заполнения новой формы
`Unable to locate element: /html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input`

Пытаюсь обновить фрейм, не могу найти фрейм в [гугл форме](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd9FQ33H5SMHelf9O1jjHl7FtLTtaTdFuC4dUFv-educaFiJA/viewform?vc=0&c=0&w=1&flr=0&gxids=7628), пробую frame(0) и ожидаемо получаю
`Unable to locate frame with index: 0`

```
    for element in range(len(row)):
        first = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
        last = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
        mail =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
        last.send_keys(row[0])
        first.send_keys(row[1])
        mail.send_keys(row[2])
        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/span')
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        
        element_count +=1
        driver.switch_to.frame(0)
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Очевидно, есть некий id у страницы, но я его не могу лоцировать.
Любой пинок в верном направлении будет высоко оценен!